# How to create an empty tar file in AIX

Tags: shell, tar, aix

How do you create an empty tar file in AIX?

`$touch myfile.tar` doesn't work.

Comment: It would seem POSIX does not allow empty tar files (`tar -c -f empty.tar` without at least one file name complains about missing files). Is this an x-y-problem? What is your problem solved with an empty tar file?

Comment: @Jens I need to run several commands and add the returned files to a tar archive. Problem is that each of the commands can return 0 files. The second command would add files to the tar archive. The simplest solution would be to create an empty tar at the beginning and just add to it. Otherwise I will need to check with if-then

Comment: You can create an empty tar file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=empty.tar bs=512 count=1` but you cannot append files to it with AIX!tar (with Gnu!tar you can). The trivial workaround is adding a dummy file such as `ReadMe.TXT` containing some text like _files are restored from tar-archive_

Comment: And at the end of the process you can remove the first 1024 bytes of the archive with `dd skip`

Answer (score 3):

Just creating an empty file will not be recognized as a tar-file. To be recognized as a tar-file, it must satisfy a particular format. There are multiple tar-file formats. An overview can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Formats.html).

The IBM AIX operation system seems support the United States Tape Archiver (USTAR) format as well as the old UNIX format [[AIX 1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=formats-tar-format-tar-archives#taf)] and does this trough the command `tar` [[AIX 2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=t-tar-command)]. It can also deal with other interchangable formats such as pax [[AIX 3](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=p-pax-command)] and cpio [[AIX 4](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=c-cpio-command)] via the commands `pax` and `cpio`. The USTAR format and the interchangable formats, pax and cpio, are all POSIX defined [[POSIX 1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html)]

Not directly supported by AIX, but worth mentioning is the wide-spread GNU-tar format [[GNU 1](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html)].

All mentioned archiving formats have a similar format: a sequential list of file objects (meta-data and file content) followed by two zero-filled blocks (a block is 512 bytes big).

This means that, in order to create an empty tar-ball, you need to have **no** file objects but two zero-filled blocks. In other words, have minimally 1024 zero bytes in your file. The following two commands generate such file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=empty.tar bs=512 count=2
$ head --bytes 1024 /dev/zero > empty.tar
```

**Note:** there is something called *blocking* which just tells the system to perform IO-operations in chunks of `BLOCKING_FACTOR * 512` bytes. In most systems (GNU, AIX) this value is set to 20 and unneeded garbage bytes are converted to zero's. That is why an empty file, generated with GNU tar is 10240 bytes big.

```
$ tar -cf empty.tar --files-from=/dev/null
$ stat -c "Size: %s" empty.tar
Size: 10240
$ od empty.tar
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0024000
```

Comment: Your answer helped improving mine, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POSIX [`pax`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/pax.html) command for generating an empty TAR archive:

```bash
pax -x ustar -w < /dev/null > empty.tar
```

Different OSs will generate different file sizes (ranging from 1024 to 10240 Bytes in my tests), all of those containing only `NUL` Bytes. Hence, an other possibility would be to use `dd` for generating the empty TAR file.

**remark:** With the POSIX TAR header being defined as 512 Bytes, I don't understand why the generated files are bigger than that.

---

When you "untar" any of those files with:

```bash
tar xvf empty.tar
```

It gives no output, no error, and doesn't create any file nor directory.

Comment: I can create the empty tar file, but when I run:
"tar -rf empty.tar a.txt"
I get:
"tar: Unexpected end-of-file while reading from the storage media."

Comment: @Fravadona The reason why there are bigger files is because tar is optimized for IO-handling on tapes.  Apparently it is more efficient to always read/write 20*512 bytes = 10240 bytes in a single go. So no matter what, they always write in chunks of 10240 bytes. If less bytes are needed, they fill it with zeros. So the tar archive by `pax` or `gnu tar` is 10240 bytes big, but only the first 1024 bytes are used as the end-of-archive indicator. The remaining 9210 bytes are just garbage and not looked at.

Comment: @Roland in the end, you weren't only trying to create an empty TAR file, you were also looking on how to add a files to it. You should have asked an other question referencing this one.

Comment: @Fravadona For me it was always implicit that you should be able to add files to the empty tar archive. I didn't consider the possibility that it is possible to create a valid empty tar file in AIX yet AIX!tar will not be able to add files to it.

Answer (score 0):

An empty file won't do, it has to contain some zeroes (n*512 bytes) -- this comes from tar being *tape archiver.* (This zeroes are interpreted as *EOF,* that's  why you cannot simply concatenate the output of more `tar c` commands.)

A file containing n*512 zeroes can be used with `t` (toc) and `x` (extract) operations, but not whith `r` (append) operation (at least with AIX's default `tar`).

Still you can create an archive containing a dummy file, which you can even remove at the end of the process with `dd`. Example script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ev

export PATH=/usr/bin

# create 'collect_tmp.tar' with a dummy file in it

echo 'These files have been restored from a tar-archive.' >ReadMeFromTar.TXT
tar -cvf collect_tmp.tar ReadMeFromTar.TXT
rm ReadMeFromTar.TXT
ls -l collect_tmp.tar

if [ $# -gt 0 -a "x$1" = 'xempty' ]; then
    echo empty
else
    # add some files into it 'collect_tmp.tar' with a dummy file in it

    tar -rvf collect_tmp.tar /etc/motd
    tar -rvf collect_tmp.tar /etc/hosts
    tar -rvf collect_tmp.tar "$0"

    tar -tvf collect_tmp.tar
fi

dd if=collect_tmp.tar of=collect.tar bs=1024 skip=1
rm collect_tmp.tar

tar -tvf collect.tar
```

Notes:

1. The error message you get from AIX!tar when trying to append an empty (or containing n*512 zeroes) tar file:
   `r tar: Unexpected end-of-file while reading from the storage media.`
2. Why 1024 bytes: `tar` adds 512 bytes long header (or a multiple of 512 in special cases) before the content of the file, and it stores the content padded with zeroes to n*512 bytes. So an empty file takes 512 bytes, a short file (like above) takes 1024 bytes in the tar-archive.

Off-topic: `GNU!tar` is way superior to `AIX!tar` (you can say it is over-featured), but is still adds these tailing zeroes (because of POSIX-compatibility, tape-compatibility, inertia) which is no problem, unless you want append to a compressed archive -- the zeroes between the old and new files won't be removed. Workaround:

```
/opt/freeware/bin/tar -b 1 ... -cf - |\
/opt/freeware/bin/head -c -1024 |\
/opt/freeware/bin/xz >>appendtome.tar.xz
```

Comment: Do you know why append on empty tar doesn't work on AIX?

Comment: How can you be sure that the dummy file will occupy exactly 1024 bytes in the tar?

Comment: After you remove the file from the tar archive it will have less than 10240 bytes. This might be a problem because each record in a tar file should have 10240 bytes. So maybe it would be a good idea to pad the tar file with 1024 zeros? https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking-Factor.html

Comment: Nope, the size can be any multiple of 512 bytes. (Also the tailing m*512 byte zeroes are completely useless (maybe except for actual magnetic tape?))

Comment: If you are going to remove the file afterwards you could make it empty in the beginning. In this case you should only remove 512 bytes, right? That's what I'm doing in my solution.

Comment: Sounds okay -- to tell the truth I wouldn't bother with a dummy file, it doesn't require _so_ much resource if you keep it.

Comment: It consumes attention/work once you have to explain to other people where this mysterious file comes from.

Comment: "A file containing 512 zeroes" Actually it has to be two blocks of 512 zeros. See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

Comment: Well GNU manual isn't necessarily authentic regarding AIX!tar. (Also GNU has no problems with working with an actually empty file.)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond The POSIX standard of USTAR (the archiving format used by AIX tar) states that a tar-file must end with at least 2 times 512 bytes of zero's. Furthermore, if any of the files you have is bigger than 512 bytes, your `dd` will fail (512 bytes of head + blocksize of 512, leads to minimally 1024 bytes per file)

Comment: @kvantour Sorry, I don't get your point regarding `dd`; what I meant is starting the archive with a dummy file of size 1..512, which takes altogether 1024 bytes (header included). Then in the final step the first 1024 file is skipped by `dd` -- the other files in the  archive are unaffected, so are the leading zeroes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Works in Linux.

```
tar cvf your-empty-tar-filename.tar --files-from /dev/null
```

Comment: Rahul, dont work...
`tar: --files-from: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
tar: 0511-180 /dev/null is not a valid tar file type.`

Comment: the error with tar is  `tar: Unexpected end-of-file while reading from the storage media.`

Comment: Works for me, on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: The question was regarding AIX, not Linux.

Comment: @Fravadona doesn't help you if can't change the system.

Comment: Please remove this answer since it doesn't contribute.